# Grails ehache invalidation not working

Tags: grails, ehcache

I am testing ehcache for grails. I am not able to invalidate my cache.
My test code:
The service method:

```
@Transactional
class HelpService {
@Cacheable('newcache')
def inlineCacheService(def param) {
  println ("I am in the function")
  MyTestClass a = new MyTestClass()
  a.paramA = new Date()
  a.paramB = [
        id: "1",
        data: "f"
  ]

  return a
}
```

The code in the controller:

```
 render "<br/>4: " + helpService.inlineCacheService("test").paramA
 Thread.sleep(2000)
 CacheManager cm = CacheManager.getInstance();
 Cache myCache = cm.getCache("newcache")
 myCache.removeAll()
 render "<br/>4: " + helpService.inlineCacheService("test").paramA
```

I am getting a null pointer exception on remove all. Why the newcache can not be found? I am using this name in the cachable annotation and have it in my CacheConfig.groovy.

My CacheConfig.groovy:

```
config = {    
cache {
    name 'inlinecache'
    //Overwrite these, inherit rest
    timeToLiveSeconds 20
}
cache {
    name 'newcache'
    //Overwrite these, inherit rest
    timeToLiveSeconds 30

}
defaultCache {
    //Just inherit from defaults
}
defaults {
    timeToIdleSeconds 120
    timeToLiveSeconds 120
    eternal false
    overflowToDisk false
    maxElementsInMemory 10000
    maxElementsOnDisk 10000000
    memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"
}
}
```

With this code it works:

```
CacheManager.ALL_CACHE_MANAGERS.each { cm ->
        println (cm.getName())
        String[] names = cm.getCacheNames();

        for (String name : names)
        {
            Cache cache = cm.getCache(name);
            println (name)
            cache.removeAll();
        }
    };
```

But isn't there a better solution?

Best regards
Peter

Comment: Is `Cache` a `org.springframework.cache.Cache`? If so I think you need to call `myCache.clear()` [Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/Cache.html#clear--)

Comment: Hi, actually I am getting a null pointer exception. I tried following code:  String[] names = cm.getCacheNames();

        for (String name : names)
        {
            Cache cache = cm.getCache(name);
            println (name)
            cache.removeAll();
        } --> the "newcache" does not appear, why?

Comment: Where / how are you creating that cache? Can you post the config snippet from `Config.groovy`?

Comment: Hi, posted my Cache configuration

Answer (score 1):

I am not a Grails specialist, but what you have is most likely two `CacheManager` defined:

- one by Grails - most likely a named one
- then in your code snippet the `CacheManager.getInstance()` ends up creating the default un-named `CacheManager` that does not know anything about your configured cache.

So I would look up the Ehcache configuration you are specifying and I would update the code in your snippet to get to the same `CacheManager`.

Use `CacheManager.getCacheManager(String name)` to get to an existing `CacheManager`. If you pass `null`, it will get the `CacheManager` named with `CacheManager.DEFAULT_NAME`.

Comment: Hi, good idea, that answer is leading to the a solution. Look at my editet post, found some solution. but not the best one I think. Is it possible to get the cache manager by name?